# Use of Zend Framework setTagsAllowed getTagsAllowed?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-filter-strip-tags

I have some very fundamental questions about the use of the [setTagsAllowed](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Zend/Filter/Zend_Filter_StripTags.class.html#det_methods_setTagsAllowed) and [getTagsAllowed](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Zend/Filter/Zend_Filter_StripTags.class.html#det_methods_getTagsAllowed) methods used with Zend Framework's Zend_Filter_StripTags?  Specifically:

1. Where should the list of tags
   defined?  In the application's
   controller?
2. Does the array have to
   include the <> eg `'<h1>'` or just
   'h1'?
3. Does the array have to include
   the closing tags eg `'</h1>'`?

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Where should the list of tags defined? In the application's
>   controller?*

You could do that.  If you're likely to reuse the list elsewhere in your application, you might want to consider using Zend_Registry.

> *Does the array have to include the <>  ... ?*

Just 'h1'.  For example:

```
$allowedTags = array(
'a',
'b',
'em',
'strong'
);
```

> *Does the array have to include the closing tags ... ?*

No.

> *An example would be appreciated.*

Sure:

```
// permit only the <a>, <b>, <em> and <strong> tags
$allowedTags = array('a','b','em','strong');

// allow only the href attribute to be used in the above tags 
// (which should only be within the <a> tag anyway)
$allowedAttributes = array('href');

// create an instance of Zend_Filter_StripTags to use
$stripTags = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowedTags,$allowedAttributes);

// now filter the string
$sanitizedInput = $stripTags->filter($userInput);
```

Does this answer your question?