# Strip HTML Tags in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to strip all html tags except `<p>,<br>,<strong>,<b>` from input data from the following:

```
    public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->fields = array(
        'name' => 'Name',
        'age' => 'Age',
        'profile' => 'Profile',
    );

    $this->mdata = array();
    $this->verify = true;
}
```

Anyone knows how to apply Zend_Filter_StripTags in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your problem:

```
$allowedTags = array('p','b','br','strong'); // Allowed tags
$allowedAttributes = array('href'); // Allowed attributes
$stripTags = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowedTags,$allowedAttributes); // instance of zend filter
$sanitizedInput = $stripTags->filter($input); //$input is input html
```

[See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069805/use-of-zend-framework-settagsallowed-gettagsallowed/1070052#1070052)

Comment: In your above code, there are just initialization of some variables and calling init() of parent. How do you want to use these with **Zend_Filter_StripTags**

Comment: I see, so I suppose I should have the StripTags in other place, thanks for that